# Абсолютное позиционирование при скролле

Tags: html, jquery, css

У меня есть окошко, в котором активен *scroll*. Пока *scroll* на месте, всё чудесно, но если прокрутить вниз, то абсолютно позиционированный элемент начинает съезжать.

Вопрос: можно это как-то исправить средствами *css* либо подстройкой *jquery*? Уже много сделал, обёртывать еще в один контейнер не хотелось бы, много ивентов переделывать придётся. Меня устроят любые пути, кроме добавления новых элементов.

Как сделать так, чтоб мой список двигался вместе с прокруткой?

```js
$('.content').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  background-color: #eee;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="scroll">
    <p class="content">content1</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content2</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content3</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content4</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content5</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content6</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content7</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content8</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content9</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь для *scroll* `position: relative;`

```js
$('.content').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  position: relative; /* Это! */
  background-color: #eee;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="scroll">
    <p class="content">content1</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content2</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content3</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content4</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content5</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content6</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content7</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content8</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="content">content9</p>
    <ul class=hidden>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Суть в том, что у вас высота считалась от самого окна. Когда я добавил `position: relative`, то высота начала считаться от элемента `.scroll`

Comment: я так делал, и меня это не устраивает, потому что при нажатии на нижнюю строку, список прячется, а мне нужно, чтоб он был всегда виден

Comment: @ke1evra, по другому только скриптово, как-то. И то, тогда не будет скрываться, если вверх листать